# Eigenstates in a 2D metal disk with finite-size perpendicular magnetic field (Piece-wise Gauge)

Tags: quantum-mechanics, magnetic-fields, electrons, schroedinger-equation

Let's have a two-dimensional metal disk with radius R, and now I apply a uniform magnetic field B perpendicular to the disk, within the concentric part of the disk with radius r $\lt$ R. How can we compute the eigenstates and energy levels of a single electron in this system?

Normally we will calculate this kind of problem in a disk full of the uniform magnetic field, and by taking a symmetric gauge, we will get the Landau levels and the corresponding eigenstates with the degeneracy related to the size of the disk.

The tricky part here is if the magnetic field is surrounded by an area without magnetic field, how can we determine the eigenstates? The gauge should be taken as a piece-wise function now.

And in the surrounding area, the AB effect should also be considered. Then how to deal with the edge between these two areas when we are solving the Schrodinger equations?